# Calling image of nth model in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm passing 5 headshots and 5 testimonials to a template in my context using the following:

```
context = {
    'headshots': headshots,
    'testimonials', testimonials,
}
```

Each instance of the headshot model has a field of image.

Within the template, I want to write each image using the `forloop.counter`:

```
{% for t in testimonials %}
   {{ t.body }}
    <img src="{{ headshots[forloop.counter].image }}">
{% endfor %}
```

My syntax appears to be wrong and the code in the  tag is throwing an error. Any thoughts as to where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not allow indirect variable lookups in templates, possibly because it encourages "writing code" in templates. What would be cleaner is to `zip` your lists in your view:

```
context = {
    'testimonials_with_headshots': zip(testimonials, headshots),
    ...
}
```

and then

```
{% for testimonial, headshot in testimonials_with_headshots %}
   {{ testimonial.body }}
    <img src="{{ headshot.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: is it possible to zip 3 lists rather than just 2? I need testimonials, femaleheadshots, maleheadshots. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? This is Python's standard [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function, nothing specific to Django.